# Smooth Scroll no funciona correctamente en tamaño MÓVIL

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

buenas tardes.
Estoy haciendo una web y en el navegador los links funcionan correctamente, pero a la hora de verlo en tamaño móvil, al clickear los links me dejan mucho más abajo.
No se porque sucede esto, en el tamaño grande, funciona perfecto y me deja exactamente en el h2 que quiero pero en el móvil no.

Pueden ver lo que sucede aquí:
https://codepen.io/ZeR0ByTe/pen/wrbMRZ
Clickear en "Nosotros" o "Galería" y luego probarlo en versión movil.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente un amigo me pudo resolver el problema, asi que comparto la solución por si a alguien más le sirve.

He quitado la librería JS de SmoothScroll y tambien el código para iniciarlo.

```
// SmoothScroll
        var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
        speed: 2000, 
        offset: 0, 
        easing: 'easeInOutQuart', // Easing pattern to use
     });
```

Y el correcto para que no suceda que en VERSIÓN MÓVIL vaya más abajo al clickear el link es este:

```
$('a[href*="#"]')
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .click(function(event) {
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();

        var scrollTop = target.offset().top - $('.sticky-top').height();

        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: scrollTop
        }, 1000)
      }
    }
});
```

El codigo de arriba esta adaptado a lo que lo necesitaba yo, pero se baso en esto:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

Muchas gracias a todos igualmente!